# Idea behind Poincaré Bendixson theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

> The Poincaré Bendixson theorem states:
>
> If R is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ containing no fixed points and $\Psi_{t}\left ( x_{0} \right ) \in R$ for all $t\geq 0$, then, the omega-limit set $L_{\omega}\left ( x_{0} \right )$ is a periodic orbit.

Intuitively, either the trajectory is a closed orbit (which must contain a fixed point $x^{\ast}$ or it must spiral towards a closed orbit(or periodic orbit).
In either case, it is understandable that it contains a fixed point $x^{\ast}$ in either case. But since R contains no fixed point, R is an annulus with the closed orbit being an orbit around the *inner* ring.

It comes across as odd to me. So in order to understand this, I reasoned that the only this can be true is if the closed orbit in R can orbit around a point S where S is a point in some other region

D $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Or am I wrong? Can someone provide a more robust idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your theorem is difficult to read. I would recommend using full sentences

Comment: @StellaBiderman Will be edited by 5 mins from time of submission of this post

Comment: *a closed orbit (which must contain a fixed point $x^{\ast}$* – If I am not totally mistaken, *closed orbit* is just another word for *periodic orbit,* and proper periodic orbits contain no fixed points per definition.

Comment: Can you explain more what sounds odd?

Comment: Closed orbit do contain a fixed point. And closed orbit is just another word for periodic orbit. I haven't heard of proper periodic orbit so if periodic orbit does not meant the same thing as proper periodic orbit, is proper periodic orbit a sub classification of periodic orbit?@Wrzlprmft

Comment: @MarcoDisce It sounds odd -to me- because a closed orbit contains a fixed point and this closed orbit is in a region R where no fixed points are allowed to exists in R.

Comment: The region is annular actually, and the fixed point is inside the inner circle of the annulus: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pRWKM.png

Comment: @Mathematicing: I use *proper periodic orbit* to exclude improper periodic orbits such that only contain one point. Compare to *proper subset* vs *subset. — Closed orbit do contain a fixed point.* – Seriously: How? If the dynamics reaches the fixed point, it can not get away from it (otherwise it wouldn’t be a fixed point). But then it cannot continue the periodic motion.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Let me give deeper thoughts to this. WIll check back in if I have questions.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft 
Under the properties of Poincare index, "Every periodic orbit contains at least one fixed point"

Comment: @Mathematicing: Where did you get that from? On another note: Could it be that *contain* is meant in the sense of *surround* here?

Comment: Your description is fine, but also quite confusing. As always, "contains" means "is inside in the sense of Jordan's curve theorem". But @Marco Disce has already detailed this, since he has given you a prototype of the possible behavior (it could in fact also have infinitely many periodic orbits accumulating in one periodic oribit). On the other hand, it is quite nontrivial that "it is understandable that it contains a fixed point", the proof is delicate.